# Как грохнуть dispatch_async?

Tags: асинхронность, ios

У меня в программе необходимо в фоне подгружать новую инфу в json и загружать ее в бд и я запускаю это так

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    //загружаю json
    //запускаю запись в базу предварительно заблокировав NSManagedObjectContext
});
```

все проходит отлично, но когда пользователь уходит с этой активити на предыдущую или любую другую, то срабатывает *viewWillDisappear* и если в фоне дейтсиве еще не завершилось, то приложение вешается..
возникает вопрос: как при *viewWillDisappear* грохнуть фоновую задачу в dispatch_async? гугл не дал ответа( в андроиде есть AsyncTask который можно отменить, а тут пока не пойму.

Подскажите разгадку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что остановить блок, который *выполняется в данный момент*, нельзя.

> Нельзя, например, по причине того, что блок, по своей сути является *анонимной функцией*, к которой нельзя обратиться напрямую - для этого её следует обернуть в оболочку, наподобие `NSBlockOperation` (см. ниже).

Можно лишь приостановить выполнение *дальнейших действий* в какой-либо очереди (`operation queue`) либо группе (`dispatch group`), используя, например, [`dispatch_suspend()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_suspend).

В вашем случае, возможно, будет удобнее использовать `NSOperationQueue`, исполнение элементов которой можно приостановить в любой момент, используя метод `-cancel`  у [`NSOperation`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=nsoperation&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fdocumentation%2FCocoa%2FReference%2FNSOperation_class%2FReference%2FReference.html&ei=7Do6UOHcHYj74QTp0YHoAw&usg=AFQjCNGiwdmylcJ0sIRQPvdtlMzBbLeoVg) и [`NSBlockOperation`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=nsblockoperation&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fdocumentation%2FCocoa%2FReference%2FNSBlockOperation_class%2FReference%2FReference.html&ei=EDs6UI-AN6Gn4gSZloGQDA&usg=AFQjCNFZ6GKGZUMkbxP-eSY9x_b0Q804dw).

---

Ссылки:

- [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)
     Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)
- [NSOperationQueue Class
     Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Спасибо!

Воспользовался:

NSOperationQueue *_queue;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [self startDownloadInBackground];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [_queue cancelAllOperations];
}

-(void)startDownloadInBackground
{
    [_queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
        NSData *responseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [self makeURL]];
        //парсим полученное
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    }];
}

Answer (score -1):

Сразу скажу, с dispatch_async никогда не работал, но в iOS есть потоки выполнения NSThread, я в таких случаях создавал метод который нужно выполнить в фоне и переменную типа NSThread, дергал метод на выполнение с помощью performSelectorInBackground, запоминал поток с помощью [NSThread currentThread] в упомянутую выше перменную и соответственно мог эту нить отменить с помошью cancel. Не знаю, насколько подойдет Вам, названия мог переврать т.к пишу по памяти